# Remove the empty tag (geometric-cyclicity)

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, tagging, tag-management

Typically, the tags with no questions are automatically removed by a script which runs once a day, this process is called [tag pruning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info).

However, there is a known bug which causes that if both tags in a tag synonym have zero question, they cannot be removed by this script. See this bug-report: [Auto-delete orphaned tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317928).
This post contains even the query to find such instances, at the moment it returns one such synonym [on the main site](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/922774/orphaned-tag-synonyms) and nothing [on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/922774/orphaned-tag-synonyms).

One can even check that when searching among tags, the tag [geometric-cyclicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-cyclicity) is displayed. You can even see the synonym [geometric-cyclicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-cyclicity)$\to$[cyclicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclicity) in the [list of tag synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) - you'll need to go back to December 2014 when it was created. (I've added both screenshots below.)

This issue was mentioned in the tagging chatroom [back in 2020](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/an-orphaned-tag-synonym). Today I asked [one of the moderators about this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2023/12/5), following the recommendation from there I mentioned the issue here on meta.

A screenshot showing what I get when searching among the tags:

[image: Screenshot]

A screenshot from the list of the tag synonyms:

[image: Screenshot]

When searching for the posts which had the tag [cyclicity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclicity), SEDE [returns only a single question](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1105163/questions-which-had-the-given-tag-including-the-editor-who-added-it?tagname=cyclicity), here is a [direct link to the revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1069108/revisions).
SEDE returns [no deleted questions tagged cyclicity](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/883845/deleted-questions-with-a-given-tag?Tagname=cyclicity).

---

A related question - if somebody stumbles upon a tag synonym like this, what is the right thing to do? Is asking on meta the safest option? (Although I assume that things like this are rather rare.)

Comment: After consulting with other moderators, it seems that removing the link between the two tags should allow the tags to be deleted.  I have, therefore, un-synonymized the two tags.  They should both be removed at the next cleanup.  I have also marked this post [meta-tag:status-review], in order to bring the bug in the tag system to the attention of staff.

Comment: I no longer see this tag when searching in the list of tags - I posted a screenshot [in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64813807#64813807).
So I suppose this could be considered as resolved. (Unless somebody see some other place where the tag appears.) Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: For this particular tag, the problem is resolved.  However, I do think that the non-deletion of empty tags which have synonyms is a problem.  I would call it a bug, and have tagged this question so that SE staff can weigh in on whether or not this is something which should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we won't be able to prevent this from happening in the next 6-8 weeks. After some investigation, we found the impact is pretty small, only about 20 instances network-wide, and as pointed out by Xander, there are still some things we can do to prevent it.

I am marking this bug as declined, but it is on the backlog to be fixed at some point greater than 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.